# adMob XML:The following classes could not be instantiated: - com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

Tags: java, android, xml, admob

few days ago i developed an android app..i wanted to put ads in that app but before i do that i wanted to test Ads on another simple app...i followed every single procedure step by step bundling the lib and everything bla bla 
but the problem is in layout even in a simple ad view app
the problem is that layout says"The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView"

and one thing this is my first post on stackoverflow...i have been fighting with this error for 3 days but i could not find the solution so i came here

This is my XML here

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.adtest.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="INSERT_YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.adtest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
           android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation
   |screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    </application>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

   </manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

The google play meta-data element:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

should be placed within `<application>` in the xml and not after that.

See also the [google play services setup guide](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html).

Comment: i did this but the same problem,project clean,even deleted old adt and downloaded new as well as jdk but same problem

Comment: Make sure you have set the correct `ads:adUnitId`. Does it start with "ca-app-pub-"? Can you see an ad unit with this id in the admob dashboard?

Comment: everything is correct but i can't solve the problem :(
and yes it starts with ca-app-pub

Comment: then it looks like google play services wasn't added correctly to your project.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this message in your IDE then it means that your IDE is not correctly loading the GooglePlayServices library into its layout editor. Fixing this is IDE specific.

But the good news is that this only affects a rendered view of your layout in your IDE. It doesn't affect your app at runtime. And you can always edit your layout using the XML editor, which IMHO will give you the best understanding of your layout.

Comment: app crashes before it runs on emulator or devices..i think this is the problem in IDE but how do i come to know if the problem is in IDE..there are all files of google play services in package explorer

Comment: Does your app run on a device? If so, there is no problem with it, only with the IDE setup.

Comment: No apps does not run on device

Comment: Then it means that you have not included the Google Play Services library in your app.

Comment: Thanks william,still there is not instantiated error but ad works in emulator.Thanks a lot!!